# Using markdown in Trello to populate email subject and body

Tags: trello, markdown

I am trying to populate an email address with a subject line and body text [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto).

This works just for the email `[link](mailto:myemail@gmail.com)` but once I start adding the subject it does not work any more.

`[link](mailto:myemail@gmail.com?subject=free chocolate)`

Is there something about markdown I am not understanding or is it a Trello limitation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use %20 to represent spaces. Here is the correct code:

```
[Click here to open a template email](mailto:abc@xyz.com?Subject=Subject%20Text&Body=Thank%20you)
```

Comment: Use %20 instead of the space in the subject line.